# Relationship between file/folder's owner and group?

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I found that a directory with following `ls` output in my system:

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 username   root  4096 Jan 14  2015 DIRNAME
```

It rose a question for me: Is there any restriction between files owner and group? I mean that each user in the system belongs to predefined group(s). Is it possible to assign a "group" to a file/folder that the file user (owner) does not belong to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to assign a "group" to a file/folder that the file user (owner) does not belong to?

Certainly. For example:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 8
-rw------- 1 muru     crontab 1136 Jul 21 12:30 muru
-rw------- 1 root     crontab 1090 Jan 20  2015 root

$ groups
muru adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ groups root
root : root
```

As you can see, neither `root`, nor `muru`, are members of `crontab`, yet the crontab files' group owner is `crontab`.

> Is there any restriction between file's owner and group?

None at all<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, there are restrictions on each individually: the UIDs and GIDs have to be 32-bit integers (IIRC), or the username and group names must exist:

```
# touch /tmp/foo
# chown 1000000000:2000000000 /tmp/foo
# ls -l !$
ls -l /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000000000 2000000000 0 Sep 15 09:04 /tmp/foo
# chown gibberish:garbage /tmp/foo
chown: invalid user: ‘gibberish:garbage’
```

But, no, no relation between owner and group.